# CPU Credits in AWS EC2

Tags: aws-ec2, aws-cost-explorer

I would like to unserstand better how AWS cpu-credit usage give me some insight about cost savings.

AWS costs may be extremely complicated to understand.
CPU size, cpu-credits, and so on.

I try to get my service running stable, fast, and smooth so, from time to time, I test different cloud providers.
AWS costs are usually 2 or 4 times higher than Digital Ocean-like cloud providers.

In this example, I have a t3.large instance with the below monitoring charts.
Since I am always generating more than consuming credits...

Is it correct to say that my instance is over-dimensioned?
I mean, would I be saving money and achieving the same performance if I had chosen a t3.medium instance?

Here are the weekly charts for:
CPU Usage, Credit Consumptions, Credit Balance:

[CHARTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxnIR.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: If you rely on VM's cloud providers tend to be expensive. What you pay for is the flexibility and management tools, which is of no interest if you have a single VM instance.

Comment: moreover is product recommendations are also off topic. but if your in the EU, netcup or heiße seems to be a option

Comment: This is not a question about product recommendation.
This is a question specific to AWS cpu-credit and how to save money with that information.
If someone out there knows well how it works, I appreciate an answer.